# Hoe wo resolve this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'api')"?

Tags: angular, api, error-handling, localhost, undefined

```
refreshData() {
    this.webService.users_GetUsersByType(2).subscribe(
      apiResponse => {
        // Set grid height to go to the bottom of the browser window.
        const grid = document.getElementById("grid");
        const newGridHeight = window.innerHeight - grid.getBoundingClientRect().top - document.getElementById("grid-footer").getBoundingClientRect().height;
        grid.style.height = newGridHeight + "px";
        this.updateGrid(apiResponse);
      }
    );
  }
  updateGrid(apiResponse: UsersResponse) {
    if (ApiResponse.checkStatus(apiResponse)) {
      this.rowDataGrid = apiResponse.contractors;
      this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.rowDataGrid);
    }
  }
```

In this above code I'm Struggling to navigate to the home page...getting this error. here Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'api')

Comment: I don't see code here that would reflect "navigation" to home page. Anyways, assuming the undefined comes from ` this.gridOptions.api`. Are you sure gridOptions has property api? Please post more relevant code or better yet, reproduce the problem online (e.g Stackblitz).

Comment: this.gridOptions is probably undefined. Is it initialized?